# $state.go to state with URL parameter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state with url parameter.
Something like:

```
.state('MyState', {
    url: '/contacts/{personName}',
    templateUrl: '/app/templates/contacts.html',
    controller: 'ContactsController',
    params: {
        personName: null
    }
})
```

now, I want to use the `$state.go` syntax and to be able to pass the `personName` param to the url with the parameter.

So for example, if I call:

```
$state.go('MyState', {personName: 'john'});
```

The address bar will show: http://localhost:8080/#!/contacts/john

Right now the address bar is showing http://localhost:8080/#!/contacts/ and I don't know how to force the url to contain the `personName`. Other than that it works fine.

Comment: the syntax might be `url: '/contacts/:personName'` which uses `$stateParams` that `$state.go()` can point to

Comment: @AlekseySolovey these 2 ways of writing are equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just add your parameters with a default value on your state definition. Your state can still have an Url value.**

```
   $stateProvider.state('MyState', {
        url : '/url',
        templateUrl : "/app/templates/contacts.html",
        controller : 'ContactsController',
        params: {personName: 'defaultName'}
    });
```

and add the param to $state.go() and navigate

```
$state.go('MyState',{personName: "MIT"});
```

Refer this:[$state.go() with Parameter](http://luxiyalu.com/reference-state-go-with-parameter/)

Hope it helps..!

Answer (score 0):

In your state definition, when you define "params" you don't have to add param in the url so replace :

```
url: '/contacts/{personName}',
```

**with**

```
url: '/contacts',
```

Comment: Exactly, "params" is here to specify what parameters will be present after the URL, you don't need to add your param in url

Answer (score 0):

While defining state use the following syntax

```
.state('myState', {
        url: '/contacts/:personName',
        templateUrl: '/app/templates/contacts.html',
        controller: 'ContactsController',
          params: {
            personName: {
              array: false
            }
          }
      })
```

Note: **"Person Name be visible in url"**

Ref: https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/tutorial/helloworld

Comment: Are you referring to the url part? If so, it is equivalent to the {} syntax. Anyway, I tried that, it's also not working.

Comment: If you are using {} then u need to use "resolve". Check out example in "https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/tutorial/hellosolarsystem#state-parameters"